# Como receber o item selecionado de um combo box e usar em um outro select?

Tags: php, javascript, html, combobox

Bom dia Programadores..
Preciso de um favor, seguinte tenho um combobox que é gerado através de um select   até aí tudo ok ..
preciso receber esse item selecionado pelo usuário e guardar a informação pois no próximo combobox eu uso esta informação, ou seja, eu uso esse item selecionado em um select...   o negocio é o seguinte tem varias empresas com varias filiais cada, quando o usuário selecionar a empresa dele, quero que no próximo combobox apareça as filias da empresa selecionada, ta tudo andando nos conformes só falta eu guardar essa informação selecionada...  segue os códigos:

```
<select size="1" name="Empresa" id="Empresa" onchange="opcao()">
                            <option selected value="Selecione">Empresa </option>                            
                            <?php
                             for($x=0;$x<count($resposta2);$x++)
                             {
                             echo '<option value= "'.$resposta2[$x][0].'">'.$resposta2[$x][1].' </option>';

                             }?>                          
                        </select>

                        <p></p>

                        <select size="1" name="Unidade">
                            <option selected value="Selecione">Unidade</option>
                                <?php
                             for($x=0;$x<count($resunid);$x++)
                             {
                             echo '<option value= "'.$resunid[$x][0].'">'.$resunid[$x][1].' </option>';
                             }?>          

                        </select>
```

No primeiro como eu já tenho todas as empresas do sistema, eu preciso que no onchange onde eu chamo um js, seja guardado o item selecionado e use no na função chamada
segue o js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           function opcao(){
                     var x = document.getElementById("Empresa").selectedIndex;

                     var endereco = document.getElementById("Empresa").options[x].value;

                     if (endereco != "#")
                   {
                       var $unid = document.getElementById("Empresa").value;    
                             window.location = "totalpago.php?parametro=$unid"
                        alert($unid);
                   }
        </script>
```

apos guardar o item selecionado  preciso atribuir esse item no na funcao abaixo

```
function todasunidades()
     {
            include("conexao.php");

            if (!conectaBancoDados()) {
                    $resposta2 = "<center><b>Não foi possível estabelecer conexão com o Banco de Dados!</b></center>";
            }
            else


            {
                    $comandoSql = "SELECT Cod_UC, UC FROM Tab_UC where Cod_Empresa=";  é aqui que preciso usar o item selecionado...

                    $dados = mysql_db_query($bancoDados, $comandoSql) or die (mysql_error());
                       $x=0;
                    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($dados))
                    {

                            $resunid[$x][0] = $linha["Cod_UC"]; 
                            $resunid[$x][1] = $linha["UC"]; 
                            $x++;
                    }
            }

            return $resunid;
    }
```

e no cod_empresa, eu preciso usar o item selecionado..
se alguém intendeu e poder me ajudar agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de usar um windows.location você deve usar um **ajax request**

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "totalpago.php?parametro="+$unid, true);
xhttp.send();
var unidades = xhttp.responseText;
```

Para evitar que a call do ajax seja feita quando selecionar a opção Selecione faça um if para validar se o valor o do Selecione como neste exemplo
https://jsfiddle.net/6k3hh598/2/

referente a sua função php você deve dar um get do parâmetro que você está passando

```
$comandoSql = "SELECT Cod_UC, UC FROM Tab_UC where Cod_Empresa=" .$_GET['parametro];
```

a resposta você devolve em formato json

```
return json_encode($resunid);
```

seu script final do js deverá ser algo como

```
function opcao(){
  var x = document.getElementById("Empresa").value;
  if (endereco != "")
  {
    var x= document.getElementById("Empresa").value;    

    //Chamada ajax
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "totalpago.php?parametro="+$unid, true);
    xhttp.send();
    var unidades = xhttp.responseText;

    //Aqui você deverá fazar a lógica para alimentar o select

  }
}
```